# Real analysis, Uniform boundedness and Uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, limits, uniform-convergence, lipschitz-functions

Suppose that $f_{n}$be a sequence of real-valued functions that are uniformly Lipschitz and uniformly bounded on $\left[0,1\right]$,there exists constants $K,M>0$ such that for all $n\geq 1$ one has $|f_{n}(x)-f_{n}(y)|\leq K|x-y|$ and $|f_{n}(z)|\le M$,$\forall x,y,z\in \left[0,1\right]$. Prove that there exists a subsequence of
$f_{n}$ that is uniformly convergent on $\left[0,1\right]$. Provide a counterexample if uniform boundedness is dropped.

I do not have any idea but I know all the definitions in the question.

Comment: Have you heard of the Arzelà–Ascoli theorem before?

Comment: No, I do not know.

Comment: Then you may want to check that theorem and the proof of it out.